# all modules that use the field api module

Tags: entities

Sorry if this is a basic question, is there a way to browse all modules created with the fields api. I am looking for some interesting ways to format and use fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the info to format fields in the [field API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/7)

- If you want to know how **core modules** implements the Field Api, you have to enter in every hook info page and there you will find the modules that implement this concrete hook. You can also follow the links to see the code.

  Here an example of [hook_field_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_delete/7) and the location on web page:

[image]

- On the other hand, if you want to know what **contributed modules** have implemeted the field API, you will have to look in the [contributed modules page](https://drupal.org/project/project_module) and make a filtered search with *core = 7.0* and *module categories = Fields*.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I have built a few custom content types and wanted to view what available field types/widget modules that are out there. For example, the URL and Link Module. Trying to see what it possible without building my own.

Comment: The only way i Know is navigating through the [contributed modules page](https://drupal.org/project/project_module). Filter the search to: _core = 7.0_ and _Module categories = Fields_

Comment: Take a look to the [example module](https://drupal.org/project/examples). It's really interesting if you want to learn.